# Is it possible to have multiple classes for Firebase RecylerView.Adapter?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently working on a Android project and I use Firebase for database. I have user and user's sharing information in database. And I use different classes for each sharing type to save to the database. And I need to get all kind of sharing data classes from the database and use in RecylerView.Adapter class to display them on the screen, is it possible ?

Comment: Please edit your question to be more specific about what classes you're working with (show the code) and the specific problem you're running into.  As I read it right now, it's difficult to understand what you're doing.

Comment: i think op question is if he can parse data from firebase that is uploaded by different classes in the app

Comment: Assume that we have 2 classes named A and B. A class has variables about photograph sharing, and B class has variables about event sharing. I save them to the database and I need to display both A and B data on the screen using RecylerView.Adapter. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with the query that you will use in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter , you can parse all the data from your firebase database to any recyclerview

to get involved into FirebaseRecyclerAdapter you can start here

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database

Edit: so, your database will be full of information, when you need to parse that information, you will do it with a query, this query is like this for the recyclerAdapter

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference()
        .child("chats")
        .limitToLast(50);
```

So , modify it to your needs and you will have all the data you are uploading with your diferent classes. Think that no matters in which classes are you uploading the data, the data will be at the same place

happy coding